# Jenkins Install, Service Start failure

Tags: windows, installation, service, jenkins

Trying to install Jenkins as the sole administrator user on Windows 7, with UAC turned off, the following error appears:

[image]

Nothing I have tried has been able to fix this, the system installed fine from the same file (though I did reinstall to check) on another PC running the same OS with the same settings

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution based on this [answer by Jan](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/jenkinsci-users/txbnxg_4azA/zAy6XSmEmoIJ) The issue is that Windows is looking for the certificate for the service and your server does not have access to the Internet. Your best option is to enable Internet access to the server for the installation of Jenkins. You wont need it once Jenkins is installed.

You could also try to disable certificate checking this way (though I'm unsure if this will work.)

1) Create the directory: `C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins`

2) Create a text file named `jenkins.exe.config`

3) Add the following text to the text file:

```
<configuration> 
  <runtime> 
     <generatePublisherEvidence enabled="false"/> 
  </runtime> 
</configuration>
```

4) Run setup as an `Administrator`

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem on a Windows XP box.

In my case, the reason the service couldn't start was that the Application Event Log was full. That is, after clearing the Application Event Log, the service started without a problem.

Maybe checking your event logs (eventvwr.msc) is a starting point.